# X-Hub-Signature on Facebook's Messenger Platform Webhook

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-webhooks

**Hi there, I have a problem with recreating x-hub-signature in the code.**
Here's what they say on official documentation:

> The HTTP post request will contain an X-Hub-Signature header with the
> SHA1 signature of the post payload. The signature is calculated using
> the keyed-hash message authentication code (HMAC) where the key is the
> app secret. The signature is then prefixed with sha1=. Your callback
> endpoint can verify this signature to validate the integrity and
> origin of the payload.
>
> Please note that the calculation is made on the raw escaped unicode
> version of the payload, with lower case hex digits. For example, the
> string äöå will be escaped to \u00e4\u00f6\u00e5. The calculation also
> escapes / to /, < to \u003C, % to \u0025 and @ to \u0040. If you just
> calculate against the decoded bytes, you will end up with a different
> signature.

I'm creating Webhook for Messenger Platform. When I pass dynamic, every message is getting caught, but then I switched scenario, now I'm catching http request in my model, and with StreamReader i get to position 0, but when I do that every 2/10 messages is getting caught. Code for Encoding with Hmac is the same for both, if there is a need I will post that also.

I'm using .Net Core2.

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3fRV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyh6L.png)

Comment: Unicode is a combination of one and two byte characters.  So you have to make sure you are consistent with the handling of the one byte characters.  Also you have to make sure you are using little endian or big endian consistently.  You may need to reverse the upper and lower byte of the two byte characters.

Comment: @jdweng Is there facebook official docs for calculating X-Hub-Signature?

Comment: The W3C site it probably very good place to start.  The following page has many links that will help.  https://www.w3.org/TR/websub/#signature-validation   The RFC specifications are written by IEEE committees and control many industries standards.

Answer (score 0):

So I did it, using https://json2csharp.com/ then encapsulating payload in the model.

But I think best way to go is dynamic type.